# Android ConstraintLayout constraint barrier to parent

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraintlayout-barrier

I want a simple thing in my layout - align an image and text horizontally and then align that group to parent top. If the text is long and gets higher than the image, then it touches the parent top, otherwise the image will touch parent top.

[image]

How can I achieve this?
I tried setting up a barrier and constraint it to parent top, but it doesn't work:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="top"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view1,view2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**NOTE:** I cannot nest them in another layout since this is going to be an "end" layout of some animation, in start layout they are not together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Barrier` is just here to set a "virtual" & "dynamic" bottom line below the views, so no need of `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf`, just `app:constraint_referenced_ids`.

When this is done you just need to place vertically your 2 views in this new "virtual" & "dynamic" space, between Parent Top and the Barrier. That's it !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view1, view2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Short text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFmEp.png)

[Long text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBbYa.png)